# Is there an alarm clock app that takes account of personal and/or public holidays?

Tags: calendar, alarm, clock

On my current and previous Android phones (HTC Magic with stock Android 1.6, and Samsung Galaxy S with 2.1 and TouchWiz) there have been pretty good alarm clock apps that allow you to set a a variety of alarms with a variety of timing and days. This gives you the handy ability to set different alarms for weekends and weekdays, for instance. Unfortunately, I often have the experience of looking forward to a nice lie-in on a holiday but getting blasted awake too early, because I forgot to switch off the alarm.

What I'd like is an app that either adjusts the built-in alarm clock to automatically set the weekend alarm when a personal or public holiday falls on a weekday, or one that replaces the built-in alarm clock and offers this facility.

I guess it could pull info on public holidays for my country from a public feed (pretty sure Google Calendar publish one for most countries) whereas for my holidays it could pick up specific all-day appointments with certain text in from a nominated Google Calendar.

Comment: Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amdroidalarmclock.amdroid) - it pulls from calendar plus you can add custom days - I had used it long back or pick from Izzy's list of [Holiday aware clocks](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_alarmclocks#group_1114). The clock recommended first is also on Izzy's list

Comment: **Anybody** who wants to make an answer drawing on above suggestion and try for the bounty, please feel free to do so. I won't be posting since I don't have time / inclination to make a bounty worthy answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is **Sleep As Android** that reads google calendar to turn alarm off on statutory holidays and your personal days off if you put `#holiday` into a full day event title.

Some statutory holidays may not apply to you. For example in Alberta Medical Aide Day is October 18, 2018 but my workplace (like most places) is not giving it as a paid day off. As such I can put `#notholiday` into the title of an all day event in Google Calendar for October 18, 2018.

To read more see: [Sleep as Android: Sleep cycle tracker, smart alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep)

---

It's hard to imagine no one has come up with the ability to turn off the regular Monday to Friday Google Android Alarm Clock based on Google Android Calendar stat holidays plus any vacation days and personal days you add to the calendar.

---

The link states:

> *Ever been roused from a good, deep sleep on a public holiday because the alarm clock wasn't turned off? AMdroid knows the public holidays
> for your country; alarms won’t go off on these days (optional).*

I'm not sure what "optional" means. Plus there is no mention of your days off (vacation, personal days, summer floats, winter floats, birthday, etc.)